# In chrome developer panel, is there a keyboard shortcut to switch to the sources tab?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut

[image]

I know the keyboard shortcut to go to the `Console` tab is `Command` + `Option` + `j`.

1. But what's the shortcut for switching to `Sources` tab?
2. Is there shortcut to switch between all the tabs(elements, network, .etc)?

Comment: For the 2nd question, the shortcut on mac is `Command` + `[` or  `Command` + `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can switch your **Developer Tools** window tabs using 
'**Ctrl**' + '**{**' (To move Backward) and '**Ctrl**' + '**}**' (To move forward)

Comment: I tried it and on mac, it's `Command` + `[` and `Command` + `]`, thanks.

Comment: I think you meant CTRL-[  and ]  - square brackets ..? That's how my keyboard is.